# Рейтинг для товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как нужно активировать рейтинг товаров?
В вёрстке предусмотрено оставлять комментарий и ставить звёздочки для товара при детальном просмотре товара.
Видел такой код в шаблоне rating.php

```
$rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
$review_count = $product->get_review_count();
$average      = $product->get_average_rating();
```

Как его использовать?
Для каждого товара должны выводиться звёздочки рейтинга. Рейтинг со звёздами как-то активируется в админке или в коде темы?
Это желательно сделать без посторонних плагинов.

---

Также добавлю, что при детальном просмотре товара есть возможность как оставлять комментарий к товару, так и поставить одну из 5 radio-кнопок, как показано на рисунке.
Т.е. при клике на верхней ссылке "write a review", можно оставить и текстовый комментарий, как показано на нижнем рисунке, так и выбрать одну из 5 радио-кнопок. Как делать учёт этих данных?
Я так понял звёздочки закрашиваются в зависимости от количества текстовых комментариев. А как тогда с 5ю радио-кнопками?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если у вас есть дополнение к вопросу — редактируйте вопрос. В ответах это размещать не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полный html рейтинга можно вывести таким способом:

```
echo $product->get_rating_html();
```

Когда пользователь оставляет комментарий к товару и устанавливает рейтинг, то рейтинг для данного комментария записывается в мета-поле `rating` комментария. Средний рейтинг высчитывается по всем комментариям к данному товару.

Полученные цифры выводятся указанной выше функцией.

Answer (score 1):

В ВП не сильно разбираюсь но давай попробуем разобраться. Все функнции, что здесь представлены это фунции плагина woocommerce. Переходим на первое [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_mt-c_l36U) [2:33] по этой теме.

Answer (score 0):

> как нужно активировать рейтинг товаров?

В настройках?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]