# Отзывы о товаре

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, в плагине woocommerce есть возможность оставлять как текстовые отзывы, так и отзыв в виде выбора звёзд. Как я понял этот код находится в файле single-product-reviews.php
Чем отличаются эти два вида отзыва? Как они учитываются в базе данных?
У них отдельные переменные? т.е. отдельные переменные для текстового отзыва и для отзыва в виде звёзд? Вроде как от количества текстовых отзывов высчитывается количество звёзд.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Рейтинг для товара](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632896/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: SeVlad, это не дубликат вопросов.
SeVlad, какие переменные отвечают за текстовый отзыв, а какие переменные отвечают за отзывы в виде звёзд?

Comment: я там вам ответил, в каком мета-поле хранится рейтинг

Comment: А подскажите, "Чем отличаются эти два вида отзыва?" в плане обработки и хранения переменных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Текстовые отзывы - это просто комментарии к товару, они записываются и хранятся как комментарии к записи произвольного типа `product`. Отзывы в виде звезд хранятся иначе, об этом ниже.

Полный html рейтинга можно вывести таким способом:

```
echo $product->get_rating_html();
```

Функция `get_rating_html` находится в `/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php`. Данные о рейтинге (кол-во звезд) хранится в метаполях `_wc_rating_count` и `_wc_average_rating`. Вычисления проводятся в функциях того же `/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php`.

Пока точно не понимаете, что вы делаете, лезть в этот код не стоит. Для модификации рейтинга есть фильтр

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', $rating_html, $rating )
```